# Alternatives to multiple IF functions

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

Have used such formula:

```
=IF(L63=$AA$3;2;IF(L63=$AA$4;3;IF(L63=$AA$5;4;IF(L63=$AA$6;5;IF(L63=$AA$7;6;IF(L63=$AA$8;7;IF(L63=$AA$9;8;IF(L63=$AA$10;9;0))))))))
```

But now need to check more if else so above formula can not work (too many `if`s).

Tried this kind formula:

```
=IF(L25=$AA$3;2;"")&IF(L25=$AA$4;3;"")&IF(L25=$AA$5;4;"")&IF(L25=$AA$6;5;"")&IF(L25=$AA$7;6;"")&IF(L25=$AA$8;7;"")&IF(L25=$AA$9;8;"")&IF(L25=$AA$10;9;"")&IF(L25=$AA$11;10;"")&IF(L25=$AA$12;11;"")&IF(L25=$AA$13;12;"")&IF(L25=$AA$14;13;"")&IF(L25=$AA$15;14;"")&IF(L25=$AA$16;15;"")&IF(L25=$AA$17;16;"")&IF(L25=$AA$18;17;"")&IF(L25=$AA$19;18;"")&IF(L25=$AA$20;19;"")
```

But there is problem. For example `L25=$AA$3` (true) and in cell (for example cell `M1` contains the above formula) displays number `2`. That is ok. But if, for example in cell `M2` write formula `=IF(M1=2;2;0)`, it displays number `0` instead of `2`.

Where is problem?
How to get number `2` in cell `M2`?
May be there is alternative solution?

Comment: whats the data in l25 and aa3 ?

Comment: @pnuts Nice and simple solution, but that works only if the values in the target region are sorted. (MS-Excel-help): "The values in lookup_vector must be placed in ascending order".

Comment: `I25` and `aa3` are `Name Surname`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an named range (say `arrLook` containing a column of cells A>H and immediately to the right 2>10 this should work for any of A>H in L63:

> =VLOOKUP(L63,arrLook,2,FALSE)

in M2, when L63 contains A (the first item in `arrLook`).

*Edit to clarify*

If you want more 'conditions' just extend the array.
PS Please use semicolons instead of commas (to conform to your locale setting).

Comment: As before have not used `VLOOKUP` and have no knowledge how to use it, then read this http://www.timeatlas.com/5_minute_tips/general/learning_vlookup_in_excel#.UgxVs3-Bb-Y as example

Answer (score 0):

Translating your specific issue (looking up a value and returning an incrementing number), you can use a MATCH formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($AA$3:$AA$20,L25)=0,"",MATCH(L25,$AA$3:$AA$20,0)+1)
```

Generically speaking though, you could create a lookup table and then use the VLOOKUP function.  This is helpful because it can return results that are not incremental numbers:

```
    __AA__  _AB_
1
2
3   Value1     2
4   Value2     3
5   Value2     4
6   Value2     5
7   Value2     6
8   Value2     7
9   Value2     8
10  Value2     9
11  Value2    10
12  Value2    11
13  Value2    12
14  Value2    13
15  Value2    14
16  Value2    15
17  Value2    16
18  Value2    17
19  Value2    18
20  Value2    19
```

Formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($AA$3:$AA$20,L25)=0,"",VLOOKUP(L25,$AA$3:$AB$20,2,FALSE))
```

NOTE: You may need to change the commas , to semicolons ; in order for the formula to work on your version of Excel.